# Android database manager and inner DatabaseHelper class

Tags: android, database, sqlite, inner-classes

Im developing an android application with database functionality. To talk to the database im creating a DatabaseManager class, with an inner class called DatabaseHelper. Although I am having some problems with implementation, so if someone could provide a little clarity I would be grateful.

- Why is the inner class necessary for accessing the database?

Example, in an Activity

```
DatabaseManager db = new DatabaseManager(this);
db.open();
db.insert(some_values);
```

The DatabaseManager Class

```
public class DatabaseManager{

// Database details
private static final String     DATABASE_NAME = "Test Database";
// Table Names
private static final String     USER_TABLE = "User";    
// Table columns
public static final String      KEY_ROWID = "_id";
public static final String      KEY_USERNAME = "username";

private static final int        DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

private static final String     USER_CREATE =           

    "create table " + USER_TABLE +
    " (_id integer primary key autoincrement not null, " +
    "username text not null);";

public DatabaseHelper   helper;
public SQLiteDatabase   the_db;
public Context          context;

public DatabaseManager(Context c){
    this.context = c;
    helper = new DatabaseHelper(context); 
}

public void open(){
    helper.open();
}


class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    DatabaseHelper(Context context){
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db){            
            db.execSQL(USER_CREATE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }


    public DatabaseManager(Context c){
        this.context = c;
        helper = new DatabaseHelper(context); 
    }


    // Makes the_db available to the Manager class.
    public DatabaseManager open() throws SQLException{
        this.the_db = this.helper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public void close(){ 
        helper.close();     
    }


    public long insertFacebook(String uname, String pwd){
        ContentValues content = new ContentValues();
        content.put(KEY_USERNAME, uname);           
        content.put(KEY_PASSWORD, pwd);

        return the_db.insertOrThrow(FACEBOOK_TABLE, null, content);
    }}
```

Answer (score 2):

> SQLiteOpenHelper:

A helper class to manage database creation and version management.

You create a subclass implementing **onCreate(SQLiteDatabase)**, **onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase, int, int)** and optionally **onOpen(SQLiteDatabase)**, and this class takes care of opening the database if it exists, creating it if it does not, and upgrading it as necessary. Transactions are used to make sure the database is always in a sensible state.

This class makes it easy for **ContentProvider** implementations to defer opening and upgrading the database until first use, to avoid blocking application startup with long-running database upgrades.